# Any Linux SQL Server client (command line) which supports XML formatting?

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2005, unixodbc

I have to launch some batch queries from a Red Hat Server against SQL Server 2005 and I need to format the results in an XML file. I have installed `msodbcsql` and `unixODBC` in my red hat server and I can access the SQL Server via `isql`. The driver works well and I can launch SQL Server in batch mode and save the results to a file.

However `isql` only supports to use a delimiter character (`-d` option) or html format (`-w` option). I need the output in XML format tagging each column.

Any help? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server 2005 was the first version which supported native XML queries.

Try a query like this:

```
SELECT 'attr' AS [@SomeAttribute]
      ,'test' AS SomeElement 
FOR XML PATH('testPath'),ROOT('testRoot');
```

The result should be this:

```
<testRoot>
  <testPath SomeAttribute="attr">
    <SomeElement>test</SomeElement>
  </testPath>
</testRoot>
```

If this works, it should be easy to get any XML from SQL Server...

From your question I take, that your tool can deal with markups using the `-w` option. I'd try this...

Comment: Thank you Shnugo. I´m gonna try.